# Ajax requets for each page in pagination with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using Datatables and filling the data using Ajax from server side. I don't want to pull whole data at once from server but need to fetch results for a single page and when user press on next or previous link, I want to make an ajax call and fetch results on the fly for that page only.

Is it possible with datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is proper initialization

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

For complete documentation and example have a look [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery paginate plugin. It will serve exactly your purpose.

this will 
1. bring one page data at a time
2. you can set no. of records per page.
3. browse pages back and forward
4. sort records on basis of coulmns

it will look something like this 
http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/